# How to prepopulate a search bar and let user change value?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a simple search bar and I want to pre-populate it with some data. I've tried using **value** but it doesn't let the user change the value in the search bar afterward.

```
<input type="search" class="navBarSearchForm3 form-control rounded searchterm2" placeholder="search term" value={comparelinks}></input>
```

I'd like the searchbar to already have a value and let the user be able to change it. Do I need some JS for it or can it be done with just HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the handle of the change. So, you need to edit the value when the user changes something on the input it would be like:

In this case, I'd use React Hooks (useState) to be able to set one default value and being able to change it.

And finally, use that seCompareLinks when user `onChange` in the input.

You can see it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-dewdney-wj7j2?file=/src/App.js:0-543

```js
import React from 'react'; 
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [comparelinks, setComparelinks] = React.useState('default value');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setComparelinks(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input type="search" class="navBarSearchForm3 form-control rounded searchterm2" placeholder="search term" value={comparelinks} onChange={handleChange}></input>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the update of the input as well, considering you use hooks:

```
const [comparelinks, setCompareLinks] = useState()

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setCompareLinks(event.target.value)
}

<input type="search" class="navBarSearchForm3 form-control rounded searchterm2" placeholder="search term" value={comparelinks} onChange={handleChange}></input>
```